# Find $x$ for $3 \sec x \tan x - 4 \csc x \cot x = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to solve this but get stuck, perhaps I am doing it wrong.
Thanks for any help.
$$3\sec x \tan x - 4 \csc x \cot x = 0$$
$$3 \cdot \frac{1}{\cos x} \cdot \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} - 4 \cdot \frac{1}{\sin x}\cdot \frac{\cos x}{\sin x} = 0$$
$$\frac{3\sin x}{\cos^{2}x} - \frac{4\cos x}{\sin ^{2}x} = 0$$
$$ \frac{3\sin^{3} x - 4\cos^{3} x}{\cos^{2}x \sin^{2}x} = 0 $$
$$  \frac{3\sin^{3} x - 4\cos^{3} x}{\cos^{2}x (1 - \cos^{2}x)} = 0 $$
$$  3\sin^{3} x - 4\cos^{3} x= 0 $$

Comment: so $3 \sin^3 x = 4 \cos^3 x$  where neither one is allowed to be zero, then $ \frac{\sin^3 x}{\cos^3 x} = \tan^3 x = \frac{4}{3}$ so ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing your work:
$$3\sin^3x-4\cos^3x=0$$
$$\implies\tan^3x=\frac{4}{3}$$
Assuming $x\in\mathbb{R}$, so that $\tan x\in\mathbb{R}$:
$$\implies\tan x=\sqrt[3]{\frac{4}{3}}$$
$$\implies \boxed{x=\arctan\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{4}{3}}\right)}+\pi n,n\in\mathbb{N}$$

Comment: How does $sin - cos$ become $tan$?

Comment: Divide by $\cos^3x$